# Is there a 'find' function in Openlayers?

Tags: openlayers

Is there a method in Openlayers, where you can search a layer's attributes and zoom to the result, similar to GIS or Google Maps?

Eg. if you had a layer of streets, you could type in a street name, which would search through a 'streetname' field and zoom/highlight the result in your web map.

Answer (score 2):

No direct function in OpenLayer to do so, but you can use **Strategy filter** as in below example to filter features, but you need to zoom and highlight manually :

**Example:**
http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/filter-strategy.html

**Comparison operators:**
http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Filter/Comparison-js.html

But if you are fetching **remote data**, then you can use **WFS** to fetch attributes data.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to use an **extension** for Openlayers.

For example, you can find cool search function extensions [here](https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/index.html?q=search).

For example, the answer you are looking for can be provided by the `ol.control.SearchFeature` extension. This extension will allow you to search for any given feature and will be zoom to it once selected.

[image: searchfeature]

Here is a small code example of how to integrate it in your Javascript code (courtesy of the [GitHub page](https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext) containing the extensions):

```
    // Control Select 
var select = new ol.interaction.Select({});
map.addInteraction(select);

// Set the control grid reference
var search = new ol.control.SearchFeature(
    {   //target: $(".options").get(0),
        source: vectorSource,
        property: $(".options select").val()
    });
map.addControl (search);

// Select feature when click on the reference index
search.on('select', function(e)
    {   select.getFeatures().clear();
        select.getFeatures().push (e.search);
        var p = e.search.getGeometry().getFirstCoordinate();
        map.getView().animate({ center:p });
    });
```

If you just want to be able to search an address or important landmark anywhere in the world, you can use the `ol.control.SearchNominatim` extension. This extension make use of the [OSM Nominatim](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/).

[image: searchNominatim]

Comment: There's no real content to this answer, just links.  You should at least name the extensions that provide the search

Comment: this answer has been very helpful. I don't undersand why it was downvoted